# Match Preferences screen loses its background

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

Steps to reproduce:

- open [Search Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i) on StackOverflow
- double-click the "edit your job matches" icon (don't ask why please), see the "Match Preferences" screen flashes - opens and immediately closes
- click "edit your job matches" icon again, see:

[image]

Here is a [short animation](http://goo.gl/BXrjEx) demonstrating the bug.

Reproduced using the currently latest stable Chrome 47 on Mac OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out, a fix is building now.

Comment: Yup, cannot reproduce it anymore. Thanks for the quick fix!